# Energy of a symmetric matrix with $0$, $1$ or $-1$ entries

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, eigenvalues

I have a symmetric matrix with entries $0$, $1$ or $-1$ which appeared in my works in graph theory (the diagonal entries are all zero). I need a good upper bound for the energy of this matrix; i.e. "the sum of the absolute values of its eigenvalues". Can anybody help?

Bests,

Comment: "energy" is not a standard notion for a matrix. Please provide a link with a definition

Comment: @DimaPasechnik „sum of absolute values of eigenvalues“ is fine as a definition.

Comment: For a symmetric matrix, this ("energy") is just the trace norm of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

[This survey on the energy of graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02850.pdf) includes some bounds which seem useful, although without a more specific question it's difficult to pick out particular ones.